# Deleting file from Digital Ocean Space with Next (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, next.js, digital-ocean

I encountered weird behavior, while trying to delete file from S3 bucket on digitaloceanspace. I use aws-sdk and I follow the [official example](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/resources/s3-sdk-examples/). However, the method doesn't delete the file, no error occurs and returned data object (which should be a key of deleted item) is empty. Below the code:

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

export default async function handler(req, res){

  const key = req.query.key
  const spacesEndpoint = new AWS.Endpoint("ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com");
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
      endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  });

  const params = {
      Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: key,
  };

  s3.deleteObject(params, function (error, data) {
      if (error) {
          res.status({ error: "Something went wrong" });
      }
      console.log("Successfully deleted file", data);
  });
}
```

The environmental variables are correct, the other (not mentioned above) upload file method works just fine.

The key passed to the params has format 'folder/file.ext' and it exists for sure.

What is returned from the callback is log: 'Successfully deleted file {}'

Any ideas what is happening here?

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure you don't have any spaces in your key (filename), otherwise, it won't work. I was facing a similar problem when I saw there was a space in the filename that I was trying to delete.

Let's have an example if we are trying to upload a file named "new file.jpeg", then the DigitalOcean space is going to save it as "new\20%file.jpeg" and when you will try to delete this file, it won't find any file having name as "new file.jpeg". That's why we need to trim any whitespace or space between the words in the file name.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Whist this is good advice, please try to find some documentation to back this up, or leave a link and a note explaining that this is not a documented feature

Comment: Okay, I didn't find this from any documentation but tried myself doing this. And yes, you are right, I will add my screenshots above so that it could help someone.